# Why is the send_data result including only object ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render an Array defined by the @people variable in a CSV format. When I use the following code in my Controller, it returns a CSV file populated with columns of object ids (i.e. 0x59ff1c0). What am I doing wrong?

```
def index
  @filter_criteria = lambda { |ped| (ped.id.nil? || ped.mother_id.nil?) }
  @people = BuildList.build_list.persons.find_all(&@filter_criteria)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data @people.to_csv }
  end     
end
```

Comment: How did you implement the `to_csv` method on the People model?

Comment: I am using `require 'csv'` in the controller, and accessing the native method `to_csv`

Comment: Can you try the following: `@people.to_csv(:id)` please?

Comment: I am sorry but it seems that the `to_csv` is reserved for Arrays: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html (ctrl+f 'to_csv')

Comment: Maybe try something like this to "translate" your `@people` to an array: `@people.attributes.to_a.to_csv`

Comment: the @people variable does represent an array - it's not tied to a Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem until I put this in the model of my table,

```
 def self.to_csv(options = {})
   CSV.generate(options = {}) do |csv|
     csv << column_names
     all.each do |report|
       csv << report.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
     end
   end
 end
```

the data @report is NOT an array when processed here:

```
  format.xls {send_data @report.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
```

I get the data I desire, however the tab delimiting isn't working properly (yet)